# Negative 5 volt logic: is this a real thing?

Tags: digital-logic

I was onsite with a technician working on an outdated industrial control panel.  He stated offhand that the panel used "negative 5 volt logic".  I had not heard of this previously.  Is this a "standard" similar to 5V TTL? or is this more likely a proprietary design?  If it's a standard, is -5V a digital 1 or zero? and what are some common gate chips analogous to the 74xx series?

Comment: Possibly depends where you define ground?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emitter-coupled_logic

Comment: Perhaps "active low" TTL-ish logic - TTL levels, but with 0 Volts representing a logic High/True/Active.

Comment: @Janka that was a good read.  I think you have accurately pointed me to the correct logic family.  I was not previously aware of ECL, but now see why it would be a reasonable selection in this case.  Are you aware of commonly used ECL-to-TTL level converters?

Comment: I'm aware that interfacing ECL with anything else is a major PITA.

Comment: http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=MC100ELT25

Comment: Just google "ecl ttl converter" and you will find plenty.  ECL is a little strange for an industrial control panel, as ECL is (or was) intended for very high speed operation.  These days there are faster logic families but a few decades ago ECL was the way to go once the bit rate got around 100MHz or higher.  ECL also commonly uses differential inputs and outputs, which gives it good noise immunity.  I suppose that could be a reason for using it in an industrial application.

Comment: ECL now uses differential inputs and outputs.  When the first couple of generations of ECL were designed, the logic threshold was more stable with respect to the positive rail than the negative rail, so  V+ had a more predictable offset from the logic threshold than V-, so ground was identified with V+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I spoke with the system manufacturer today, who informed me it's NOT negative 5 volt logic.  It's simply *inverted* logic (open collector) which designates ground/common as logic 1 and +5 volts as logic 0.

So it was a lot simpler than I was led to believe by the tech.  LOL.  Thanks everyone for your informative answers.

Answer (score 6):

Theoretically, you could use negative logic with any logic family, but it's only commonly done with emitter-coupled logic (ECL). According to Wikipedia, ECL is more sensitive to VCC noise than VEE noise. In this system, 0V is a logic one and -5.2V is a logic zero.

Comment: PMOS logic, used in e.g. the display "memory" (shift registers) for the original Apple (not the Apple II) and also some early DRAM chips, defined switching thresholds relative to the positive rail.  When the positive and negative rails were 5 volts apart, the logic levels for a PMOS device which was referenced to the positive rail would interface directly with TTL logic that was referenced to the negative rail.

Answer (score 2):

ECL has very poor noise immunity (perhaps 0.1 or 0.2 volts). Thus I doubt ECL is being used. And it burns lotta power.

I expect the "logic" is some version of DTL DiodeTransistorLogic, high voltage swings for noise immunity, with True and False being inverted from our expected TTL/CMOS levels.

Comment: In its day, ECL was the fastest logic family available (you can still get the ECL handbook from On semi), but it has long since lost that crown. Typical power was 25mW per *gate*.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf You may be right. I have not probed anything to see what voltages are in play. It is a water distribution controller. Nothing high-speed happening. So ECL would probably be overkill and subject to noise.

Comment: ECL drew CONSTANT CURRENT in the "logic" part of the gate. Any fluctuation came from emitter-follower buffers and discrete pulldown resistors to -2 volts; Out and OutX signals often were trivially available, if you just added the pulldown. Today's CMOS is great for trashing the rails; this upsetting of VDD and injection of trash into substrate is IMHO the limiting factor in system integration.